# Why is DBX trying to quote my table name?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird, dbexpress

I've got a TSimpleDataSet connected to a Firebird database.  The dataset's internal dataset's `CommandType` is set to `ctTable`, with CommandText set to a table name.  So I expect, when I set it to Active, that it will generate a query that looks like `select * from TableName`.

Instead, for some bizarre reason, somewhere in the internals of the DB Express code it's trying to put quotes around the table name, so I end up with `select * from "TableName"`, which of course causes syntax errors.  Apparently the quotes are coming from the TSqlConnection's `Metadata` property, which is read-only, so I can't fix this in code.  (That would make too much sense, I guess.)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Mason, try setting the `commandtext` property of the `DataSet` associated to the `TSimpleDataSet` to uppercase. example change `SimpleDataSet1.DataSet.CommandText:='TableName';` to `SimpleDataSet1.DataSet.CommandText:='TABLENAME';`

Comment: @RRUZ: OK, that worked, but I don't like it.  The database is not case sensitive, and that's a good thing, and I don't want some misfeature turning on case sensitivity when I never asked for it.  What I'm looking for is a way to disable this, if there is one.

Comment: @Mason, personally i try to avoid to use the `ctTable` in the commnadType, instead try setting the `commnadType` to `ctQuery` and the `CommandText` to `select * from TableName`

Comment: @RRUZ: Because of issues like this? :P  I found a way to change the metadata with a bit of RTTI surgery, but that's an ugly hack and I'd prefer not to have to do it that way.

Comment: @RRUZ what version of oracle are case sensitive in this regard?

Comment: +1 for the _a bit of RTTI surgery_ :)

Comment: @jachguate: Oracle becomes case sensitive when you use quotes, see my answer below.

Comment: @lsandon original RRUZ comment seems deleted now, IMHO any sql-92 compliant database will support double quotes to make any identifier case sensitive, but IIRC RRUZ was talking about case sensitivity without the double quotes.

Comment: AFAIK Oracle is not case sensitive unless you create identifiers using the quoted syntax. IIRC you can create "INVOICE", "Invoice" and "invoice" tables in the same schema, but then you have to access them using the quoted syntax.

Comment: @Mason do you mind to show us what surgery was that?

Comment: @jachguate: Posted as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this solution by request.  Not going to mark it as accepted, though, because it feels like an ugly hack and if possible I'd like a more elegant way to prevent the problem:

```
procedure RTTISurgery(connection: TSqlConnection);
var
  cls: TRttiType;
begin
  cls := TRttiContext.Create.GetType(connection.Metadata.ClassType);
  cls.GetField('FQuotePrefix').SetValue(connection.Metadata, '');
  cls.GetField('FQuoteSuffix').SetValue(connection.Metadata, '');
end;
```

NOTE: I do not recommend the use of RTTI surgery techniques as a general purpose solution to programming problems.  It should only be used when no better solution is available, since it almost invariably involves violating encapsulation. (Which is the point of using it: a last-ditch solution to fix over-encapsulated bugs.)

Comment: +1 Ugly Hack, as said, but nice to have in the toolbox until that bug is fixed.  BTW, did you check QC about that?  I'll vote for it, I'm Firebird user, but not SimpleDataSet user nor ctTable commandtype fan, but I think this deserves to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Quotes can ensure tables with names that can conflict with other identifiers can still be used. Most databases - don't know FB - allow reserved identifiers to be used as object names as long as they are quoted, i.e. SELECT TIMESTAMP FROM X may not work, while SELECT "TIMESTAMP" FROM X may. IIRC it's a SQL-92 rule to allow bakward compatibility if new keywords are introduced.
Be aware that when using quoted, the object identifiers can (or must, I don't remember) become case sensitive, thereby if you have the INVOICE table, select * from "invoice" won't work, while select * from "INVOICE" will.

Comment: @lsandon, note the question is not about how double quites work, it is about DBX double quoting identifiers by default and how to disable that behavior.

Comment: Or metadata are returned that way (it looks many tools quote identifiers when asking for an object definitiom), or DBX quotes them to ensure identifiers are valid.